# .Net Core WebApp is needs clearing the site data to run

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

net core webapp.We are not using React in fronted, just boostrap. We use lazy loading, ef core,cookie vs i will give the startup code.

So when I press the IISexpress button to run aplication, says localhost redirected you to many times.

Then press `f12-> application-> clear site data` then refresh the page and it opens. It always work like tihs,why its happening and how can I fix it or maybe i should clear the site data in startup ?

Startup
ConfigureServices

```
CookieBuilder cookieBuilder = new CookieBuilder();
            cookieBuilder.Name = "DemoaApp";
            cookieBuilder.HttpOnly = false;
            cookieBuilder.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            cookieBuilder.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

Configure

```
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

Comment: What should I do to not do this repeadly

Comment: I still got this issue. How can I clear the site data automaticly